# Which database to store big metric data on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, raspberry-pi, nosql

I want to use Raspberry Pi as an independent sensor, which will measure some value each second and store this metric data into a local database. Then I would like to query the database based on the date range. Which database should I use, taking into account the limited resources of RPi and that there will be ca. 30758400 records/year? Are there any RPi-specific lightweight database engines especially for this purpose?

Comment: What about a simple sqlite database. You can copy the database file to a more powerful computer for the analysis of the data.

Comment: Will SQLite handle data so big? The thing is I don't want to involve any other computers.

Comment: 30 million rows is a lot, that's true. Especially for a Raspberry Pi. How much data per row? And what kind of queries do you want to do? How many queries?

Comment: There will be a timestamp and a numeric value in each row. I will query for max, min and avg values each hour.

Comment: You should consider the advice of @pdw to the storage medium. A SD card may not live long, even if the storage volume should be more than sufficient.

Comment: So should I use a USB flash drive instead?

Comment: As far as I know, USB flash drives are the same as SD cards. Your best bet is to reduce the amount of I/O. Buffer your measurements in memory and write them to disk once per hour. That's the sort of I/O SD cards are designed to handle.

Comment: hamsterdb can store such kind of data very compact and efficient. In addition, the next version will have built-in support for calculating average, sum etc. Min/max is also supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think SQLite will perform well in this role. You might need to tune the pragma settings a bit for the rPi (e.g. set journal_mode=WAL), but SQLite can easily handle multi-gigabyte databases. (SQLite's main weakness is concurrent access, but that won't be a problem for your application.)

If you only need to store timestamp/value data, and only query on timestamp ranges, you might opt to use a key/value store such as LevelDB. You lose the flexibility of a SQL engine, but you gain performance.

What storage medium are you planning to use? An ACID database will write to the disk for every transaction. Continuous I/O like that can quickly kill an SD-card.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, there will be just a timestamp and a value. I thought about using an internal memory or an SD card on RPi. What do you propose?

Comment: I don't believe that there's a great difference.

Comment: SQLite is also the recommended choice on [RPi forums](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=6335)